# Understanding the multicollinearity issue in relation to linear regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, confidence-interval, covariance-matrix, matrix-inverse

There are 2 issues that multicollinearity in linear regression leads to

1. Interpretability goes for a toss
2. Parameter confidence intervals are wide and it is difficult to find a parameter significant

I understand the first. For the second I reference [this](https://youtu.be/V4xOdtqic3o?t=3965)

Following is the argument in the video: (I am summarising the 3 minutes of the video from the time stamp that I have referenced above)

1. The test statistic for a model parameter that follows t-distribution is $\hat{\beta}/\sqrt{\gamma_i}\hat{\sigma}$ where $\gamma_i$ is the $i$th diagonal entry in $(X^TX)^{-1}$
2. $(X^TX)$ is diagonal if $X$ is orthonormal
3. $(X^TX)^{-1}$ would have the reciprocal (of $X^TX$) diagonal elements
4. **As we begin to have non 0 non-diagonal entries in $X^TX$ the diagonal entries of $(X^TX)^{-1}$ start to blow up leading to high values of $\gamma_i$ in the denominator of the test statistic we mentioned in the point 1**
5. As the denominator of the test statistic goes up the confidence intervals become wider

I am seeking help understanding the point 4. Why is it true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the two-regressor case helps to build intuition (let us omit the constant, which does not have covariances). Then,

$$
X'X=\begin{pmatrix}\sum_ix_{i1}^2&\sum_ix_{i1}x_{i2}\\
\sum_ix_{i1}x_{i2}&\sum_ix_{i2}^2
\end{pmatrix}\equiv\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\
b&c
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The formula for the inverse of a $(2\times 2)$ matrix gives
$$
X'X=\frac{1}{ac-b^2}\begin{pmatrix}
c&-b\\
-b&a
\end{pmatrix}
$$
When $b^2$ gets close to $ac$ (from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have that $b^2\leq ac$) we almost divide by zero, leading the diagonal elements of the inverse to blow up.

We would have exact multicollinearity if, say, $x_{i2}=mx_{i1}$, so that  the regressors are multiples of each other. Then,
$$
X'X=\begin{pmatrix}\sum_ix_{i1}^2&m\sum_ix_{i1}^2\\
m\sum_ix_{i1}^2&m^2\sum_ix_{i1}^2
\end{pmatrix}\equiv\begin{pmatrix}a&ma\\
ma&m^2a
\end{pmatrix},
$$
so that $b^2=m^2a^2=ac$ and the second column is just $m$ times the first, highlighting that the matrix would no longer be invertible.

Answer (score 1):

When $X$ is nearly multicollinear, $X^\top X$ will have at least one eigenvalue close to 0.  As a consequence, $(X^\top X)^{-1}$ will have at least one very large eigenvalue.  Since $(X^\top X)^{-1}$ is a positive definite matrix, all eigenvalues are positive.  Thus the trace (sum of eigenvalues) of $(X^\top X)^{-1}$ is very large.  The trace is also the sum of the diagonal elements.  So at least one diagonal element of $(X^\top X)^{-1}$ is very large.  Note that they don't *all* have to be large!